# Lists not instantiating C#

Tags: c#, list

Just started learning how to code. I am making a Ordering System with three objects `Customer`, `Inventory`, and `OrderForm`. I have to be able to add/save, Customer information to a .csv file. via `StreamWriter`. Also be able to edit and delete and specific information anytime I want.

Now from what I have researched it seems Lists are the best way to go about holding the information till they have been written into the file, also they are much easier to edit and delete the information.

I have a class called `Customer`, where I have put all the properties for a customer information (name, ID, state, etc.) and their get and set properties.

I have a windows Form with textfields, and buttons to input the the above mentioned data from a customer and save it (via button)

In the windows form class

I've made a List to hold that information:

```
public List<Customer> CustInfo { get; set; }
```

but for some reason this is not working:

```
CustInfo = new List<Customer>();
```

the `CustInfo` is showing a red line, and I cannot do an .Add method to it.

any thoughts?

Comment: My guess is your not trying to create a new list inside a method.  You can't do it at the class level for a property.  Without seeing code - you will only get guesses at best.  Please post code with your questions.

Comment: Did you include System.Collections namespace?

Comment: If you get a red line, read what the error text is. Post it up here if you can't understand it.

Comment: If you get a red line, press Ctrl+dot.

Comment: You say `public List CustInfo { get; set; }` is how you set up the list.. if you copied that directly from your code, then you're missing the object that you're making a List of. It should read `public List<Customer> CustInfo { get; set; }`

(Or at least that's what it said before the edit)

Comment: Compile your program and post the error message along with the relevant lines of the code surrounding the source of the error.

Comment: I am good. AD.Net hit the nail on the head. I put in the Customers.CS  where the properties are listed for the customers information. Made a

Public Customer()
{
list code
}

its working now. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class YourClass
{
    public List<Customer> CustInfo { get; set; }
    public YourClass()
    {
        CustInfo = new List<Customer>();
    }
}
```

That should work, or do the instantiation inside a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have the property instantiate it for you..some poeple dont like this method though since the property ends up checking for null each time you use it.

```
private List<Customer> _custInfo;
public List<Customer> CustInfo 
{ 
  get { return _custInfo ?? (_custInfo = new List<Customer>()); }
  set { _custInfo = value; }
}
```

Comment: Unless you are crazy worried about performance, this is a very nifty solution.

Comment: I don't like it because it way more code -- and way more confusing code, to accomplish the same thing as in AD.Net's answer -- and his is more readable.  It does give a delayed initialization, which might be useful if we were filling CustInfo from a database (but for an empty List it's kind-of pointless)

Comment: AD.Net's is more readable because it's only one property declared immediately above only one constructor. In reality, properties will become more and more disconnected from their default values as you add more of them, and need to be initialized in every constructor. Putting the default value with the declaration is more readable, and less _significant_ code (the "more code" you're talking about is simply the lack of auto-property syntactic sugar, not actually expressing more). If you don't care about delayed initialization, you can just assign directly to the private field at its declaration.